# VBscript error running with different user

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I'm working on a script that will run as a scheduled task under a local admin account.  The heart of the script is as follows:

```
'Calculate date time
dtm = Now
ymd = (Year(dtm)*10000) + (Month(dtm)*100) + Day(dtm)
hms = (Hour(dtm)*10000) + (Minute(dtm)*100) + Second(dtm)
dString = ymd & "_"  & hms
Set Wso = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Write random string to text file for reference by incremental script
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objFile = Fso.OpenTextFile("e:\backups\dString.txt", ForWriting, True)
objFile.WriteLine(dString)
objFile.Close
'Append random string to make full backup name unique'
'Execute full backup creation'
'PROBLEM: Below line will only execute under my domain account
Wso.Run("trueimagecmd /create /filename:""e:\backups\autoBackup_" & dString &"_.tib"" /compression:5 /incremental /partition:""C""")
```

The above snippet will run fine under my domain account, but will error on the line indicated above with the following:

```
The system cannot find the file specified
Code: 80070002
Source (null)
```

This error will not occur when I run it under my account.  I'm not familiar enough with the permissions required to run an instance of "Wscript.Shell".  Any insight is appreciated.

UPDATE:

trueImagecmd is a command line version of Acronis recovery software.  I'm using this script as a way of automating the process for deployment.  The command is fine and I can run this script as myself, when running under the local admin account, however, the script executes up to the point indicated, the run command is throwing the error.

UPDATE 2:

Looks like including the full path fixed the problem.  Thanks all for your suggestions.

Comment: What's `trueimagecmd`? Is that application available when running under the other user's account? Does it require administrative privileges?

Comment: Is `E:` a network drive? If so, it's probably not mapped for the account that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling trueimagecmd with the full path to the executable?
For instance C:\progra~1\trueimage\trueimagecmd.exe

Comment: Hi ariel, sorry I've been busy this weekend and haven't had a chance to work on this.  I'll try your suggestion tomorrow and post an update ASAP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have drive E in the other machine from where it generates error. Try using **c:\backups\autoBackup_" & dString &"*.tib"*** instead of **e:\backups\autoBackup" & dString &"_.tib"**